# RF limiter for -20dbm

Tags: power, rf, low-power, surface-mount, protection

I am working on a receiver in which I would like to limit the RF power at input to -10dBm to -20dBm, the receiver is working for frequency 1GHz. I Have checked pin diode limiters and shottkey diode limiters, but they work for not more then 0dBm. Is there any way i can design a limiter for the required limiting range? Are any papers available on it?

Comment: Please add more detail. You haven't actually asked a question.

Comment: Hello,  working on a receiver in which I would like to limit the RF power at input to -10dBm to -20dBm, the receiver is working for frequency 1GHz. I Have checked pin didode limiters and shottkey diode limiters, but they work for not more then 0dBm. Is there any way i can design a limiter for the required limiting range? Are any papers available on it?

Comment: Perfect! Please add that to your original question by editing it. Unfortunately, I'm not equipped to answer your question, but someone with more knowledge may be able to answer.

Comment: There are a lot of RF limiters that can handle > 0dBm what limit can you afford? But the compression range might only be 20dB at reasonable cost and 40dB at $$$   Most limiters can be designed using Pin Diodes or Schottky diodes. These can also be designed using a MMIC process. They may have spike issues or nonlinear compression

Comment: Here is an LNA with an expensive solution that handles +16dBm input  for OP1dB and 53dB gain min http://www.pmi-rf.com/Products/amplifiers/documents/TypicalcharacterisicsonPEC-53-12-10-15-SFF_RevB1.pdf  just to show what is possible  but since you dont have a spec or a budget , no answer is perfect

Comment: I have the same question. Unfortunately the link from Sunnyskyguy is down. I need to protect a device that can handle up to -15dbmW at the input at 868MHz. The rf limiter should have low insertion loss since it will be powered from a receiving antenna. I don't have a grasp on how much this costs. So an ideal answer would probably link to order options or datasheets of options at multiple price points.

Answer (score -1):

Although not an answer this is the construction of a 2~22 GHz soft limiter (almost 1GHz) to give you an idea of the cascaded stages of limiting in order to  give you more dynamic range of compression.

> Qorvo’s TQGaN15 GaN on SiC process. GaN on SiC offers high input power survivability of 40 dBm, potentially eliminating the need for a power limiter.

[image]

Comment: Speaking of "limiters", Trump ordered a cease and limit to full stop discussions of selling Qualcomm to Broadcom Presidential Order Regarding the Proposed Takeover of Qualcomm Incorporated by Broadcom Limited https://www.everythingrf.com/News/details/5803-President-Trump-Blocks-Broadcom-s-Hostile-Bid-to-Takeover-Qualcomm

Comment: You sure that not a distributed LNA?

Comment: Yes it is with distributed compression 
TGA2227
2 - 22 GHz GaN Low Noise Amplifier